# ASP .NET Core 2 Localization get all string for new language

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

There are a ASP .NET Core application with localization as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization.

The all string are localized with default language with a *IStringLocalizer _localizer["About Title"]* - no a .resx file.

Now I want add a new language.

**Can I generate all resource files a automatically?**

Example I have

```cs
private readonly IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> _localizerG;
private readonly IStringLocalizer<HomeController> _localizerC;

_localizerG["Your contact page. (G)"]
_localizerC["Your contact page. (C)"]
```

Can I generate (and update in future) a .resx files for new a language *uk-UA* with filled strings

1. SharedResource.uk-UA.resx

   - Name: Your contact page. (G)
   - Value: Your contact page. (G)
2. HomeController.uk-UA.resx

   - Name: Your contact page. (C)
   - Value: Your contact page. (C)

Comment: You can log those strings by creating a custom localizer. Then you can create required resources for those strings.

Comment: They will be logged... provided that all code paths are actually invoked. My personal opinion is that the officially recommended ASP.NET MVC pattern of using full default values in code (as opposed to synthetic keys) is quite terrible and causes issues as soon as you add a 2nd language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option you can log those strings by creating a custom localizer. Then you can create required resources for those strings.

For example, create a localizer like this:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
public class MyStringLocalizer<T> : StringLocalizer<T>
{
    public MyStringLocalizer(IStringLocalizerFactory factory) : base(factory)
    {
    }

    public override LocalizedString this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            //Log typeof(T) and name
            return base[name];
        }
    }

    public override LocalizedString this[string name, params object[] arguments]
    {
        get
        {
            //Log typeof(T) and name
            return base[name, arguments];
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `ConfigureServices` method, register the localizer:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IStringLocalizer<>), typeof(MyStringLocalizer<>));
```